# Angularjs custom directive child scope access parent scope method?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a carousel with AngularJS ans UI Bootstrap. Since the carousel in UI bootstrap only supports images, I wan to write my own directive to support youtube video.

I want the video to start to play when the video slide is active, and pause when the slide is not active. Also I would like to pause the carousel lopping when the video is playing. So far i have done the first part but can't pause the carousel because i can't access the pause method of the carousel scope.

My code:

HTML

```
<div carousel interval="5000">
    <div slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-if="slide.image" ng-src="{{slide.image}}" />
        <div ng-if="slide.video" youtube="{{slide.video}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
.directive('youtube', ['youTubeService', function (youTubeService) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var player;
            var playerReady = false;
            var playerState;
            var callback;

            function createPlayer() {
                player = new YT.Player(element[0], {
                    width: 450,
                    height: 300,
                    videoId: attrs.youtube,
                    events: {
                        onReady: function (event) {
                            playerReady = true;
                            if (callback != null) {
                                callback();
                            }
                        },
                        onStateChange: function (event) {
                            playerState = event.data;
                            if (playerState === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                                //scope.$parent.play();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            if (youTubeService.ready) {
                createPlayer();
            } else {
                scope.$on('youTubeServiceReady', function (event, args) {
                    createPlayer();
                });
            }

            scope.$watch('slide.active', function (active) {
                if (active) {
                    if (playerReady) {
                        player.playVideo();
                        //scope.$parent.pause();
                    } else {
                        callback = function () {
                            if (scope.slide.active) {
                                player.playVideo();
                                //scope.$parent.pause();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (playerReady && (playerState == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING || playerState == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)) {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/xCSwsmFisoZA7SQtQuCg

Ui bootstrap carousel code
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js

Please help, tell me if i'm doing wrong. I'm new to this angularjs framework.Thanks

Comment: Include relevant code to make your question self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `slide` directive from angular-ui-bootstrap has created an isolated scope, `scope.$parent` in the link function isn't the scope of carousel, therefore you can't access `play` and `pause` functions.

In link function, you can get the carousel's scope by calling `scope()` on carousel element:

```
var carouselScope = element.parent().parent().scope();
```

Then, use `carouselScope` to replace where you have put `scope.$parent`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1HCiqvTm1Fd9Rh0o8Mtw

Comment: what's the difference between element.parent().scope() and scope.$parent? An isolated scope doesn't have a parent??

Comment: An isolated scope doesn't prototypically inherit from the parent scope. That's for preventing the directive from accidentally reading or modifying data in the parent scope.