# Calling a directive attribute as a nested directives attribute value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**EDIT: It turns out that this actually works, it just doesn't show the content behind the 'model' attribute in the inspector. I didn't notice it because there was no content on that particular data point i was using. *Facepalm* thanks to all who helped.**

So I'm trying to make my form structure simpler, by creating a pretty verbose nested directive structure. I'm using pretty basic angular code to achieve this, but for some reason, using an attribute from the parent as the value for a child directive's attribute doesn't work (code below to explain, had to change some proprietary words but its essentially the same). What am I doing wrong?

**Parent HTML directive call:**

```
<field-label project-for="projectName" project-model="data.product.projectName">Project Name</field-label>
```

**Directive code:**

```
app.directive("fieldLabel", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    scope: { model: '=projectModel', for: '@projectFor' },
    templateUrl: 'views/products/label.html',
  };
});
```

EDIT: By Request, the other directive in use here:

```
app.directive("projectOtherView", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { field: '=projectOtherViewModel' },
    templateUrl: 'views/products/XXX.html',
  };
});
```

**Template HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
  <label for="{{for}}" class="control-label" ng-transclude></label>
  <project-other-view project-other-view-model="model"></project-other-view>
</div>
```

The 'for' works fine but the 'model' only passes through itself, not what it should be(the model name I passed through at the beginning).

Comment: What is the code for project-other-view ?

Comment: I added that in for ya.

Comment: It works fine. If your products/XXX.html contains {{field}} it displays the contents  of data.product.projectName. Don't worry that it's called model still, That's correct. see http://plnkr.co/edit/MsAHkTU3KLXWhpplWAPs?p=preview

Comment: Steve, so what you are saying is that even tho it looks like it's injecting just straight 'model' into the html, if that actually had something tied to it it should show through? so it's working it just doesn't look like it is lol BRILLIANT! thanks bro

Comment: I've changed this into an answer if you could accept and upvote it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment. The fact that it doesn't display anything other than what you've defined,  in this case the word 'model' is fine, it is still wired up to the parent model. So if you were to put the expression {{field}} into your child template, you would get access to the two way binding in the model. So your model hierarchy looks something like this:

```
level 1: data.product.projectName (binding to next level: project-model="data.product.projectName")
    level 2: projectModel (binding to next level: model: '=projectModel')
        level 3: model (binding to next level: project-other-view-model="model")
           level 4: projectOtherViewModel (binding to next level: field: '=projectOtherViewModel' )
```

Remember hyphens are removed and CamelCased so 'project-model' in a template becomes 'projectModel' in the javascript.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/MsAHkTU3KLXWhpplWAPs?p=preview for a working example.

Comment: This is the answer, Thanks Stevo. As soon as I gain 15 rep I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a jsfiddle that replicates your problem?  I have a feeling your problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123383/angularjs-custom-directive-child-scope-access-parent-scope-method)

Comment: Working on the fiddle, will link it in later once i get it replicating my issue well. (embarrassing admission, I've never fiddled before *shame*) Thanks for that link, I'll check it out.